# "Need just [verb]" vs. "need to just [verb]"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, infinitives, semi-modals

I wonder if it's okay to use these interchangeably:

> 1. You need just accept it.
> 2. You need to just accept it.

Comment: "You just need to accept it." Would be simple and clear.

Answer (score 7):

[*Need*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/need) can either be a regular verb, or a modal verb. When *need* is used as a modal verb, it does not take *to*. The modal verb is used in current day English mainly in the negative:

> It need not have happened.

but I believe that some people also still use *need* as a modal verb when it is followed by certain adverbs, which would justify the use of "*You need just accept it.*" I also believe that this usage was much more common 100 years ago.

If *need* is used as a modal verb, it does not get conjugated. Googling *"he/she/it need simply"* yields quite a few instances of this construction.

Comment: The list of adjectives the modal *need* is used before also includes *only, merely, simply, hardly.* I don't know that it's often used before *just,* but *just* definitely fits in with the rest of the list. It also sounds O.K. to me, whereas adverbs such as *He need urgently ...* don't.  So if you saw this usage somewhere, I am fairly sure that *need* was being used as a modal verb.

Comment: According to the article on  auxiliaries at Wikipedia 'The status of dare, need (not), and ought (to) is debatable' - and if they are not considered auxiliaries, they cannot be in the subset of modals. There is a semantic requirement in the definition of modals (re modality!), which I consider _need_ does fulfil. However, its syntactic behaviour resembles that of _help_ to some extent, in that it catenates with both bare infinitives and to-infinitives. _Help_ is certainly never modal by any definition. I think we're in danger of not separating permitted style of catenation from modal nature.

Comment: @Edwin: if you want to call them semi-modals rather than modals, go ahead. It's probably better terminology. But you can say (in many dialects) *"he need not take", "he dare not take", "he ought not take"*. You can **never** say *"he help not take".*

Comment: Wikipedia: The verbs/expressions dare, ought to, had better, and need not behave like modal auxiliaries to a large extent, although they are not productive in the role to the same extent as [should, may ...]. Furthermore, there are numerous other verbs that can be viewed as [']modal verbs['] insofar as they clearly express modality in the same way that the verbs in this list do, e.g. appear, have to, seem, etc. In the strict sense, though, these other verbs do not qualify as modal verbs in English because they do not allow subject-auxiliary inversion, nor do they allow negation with not.

Comment: @Edwin: I don't understand your point. I largely agree with Wikipedia here, although I would add that *ought, dare, need* have somewhat different syntax in different dialects.

Comment: I'm saying that there is a conflict in meaning between the uses of the word 'modal', so that (as in the Wikipedia article above) verbs can be viewed as _modal_ verbs in that they relate to this sense of modality: (AHDEL) ...     

**3. Logic The classification of propositions on the basis of whether they assert or deny the possibility, impossibility, contingency, or necessity of their content.**           but are not viewed as _modal verbs_ because they do not fulfil the syntactic requirements agreed upon.

Comment: In fact, the definition of _modal_ (linguistics sense) given by Collins seems to suggest rather than demand the syntactic requirement: **modal  2. (Linguistics / Grammar) Grammar (of a verb form or auxiliary verb) expressing a distinction of mood, such as that between possibility and actuality.**

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not okay to use these interchangeably. They both work, but it depends on what they precede.

> You need a car to get there.

Here, *need* is followed by a noun, therefore no *to*.

> You need to get there as fast as possible.

Here, *need* is followed by a verb, therefore a *to* is required.

Both in one sentence:

> You need a car to get there and you need to get there as fast as possible.

In your example, *accept* is a verb, therefore a simple sentence would look like this:

> You need to accept this.

By inserting *just*, you can extend it to:

> You just need to accept this.

Or probably other forms, which should still be correct, but less common:

> You need just to accept this.
>   You need to just accept this.

Either way, *to* is never ommited, as it was in the first, simplest example.

Comment: This grammatical requirement of *to* is observed more in the breach in today's speech and some writing practice -- it is quite common to say "You need just accept this."

Answer (score 1):

In conversational American English, you should use an article or "to" following "need".

> You need to do this.
>
> You need a new car.
>
> Does he need a pen?
>
> She needs to accept this.

It isn't "wrong" to omit the article or "to", but it is rather uncommon. If you do it you're going to sound like a know-it-all, and risk coming across as very rude.

*Update: Case in point, see the comments.*

The negative form, "need not" or "needn't", is less pompous but still very formal:

> You needn't raise your voice.

A teacher might scold a student in this way.

Saying "need just **_**" is going to sound unusual and <s>incomplete</s> haughty to an American audience.

Comment: One need but expand one’s reading a bit to see that this is anything  but true.

Comment: Your comment does more to prove than disprove my point.

Comment: I meant beyond whatever it is you are reading that has so impoverished a set of syntactic constructs as not to contain modal *need*. What I wrote is perfectly palatable in American English. Things like *he need only* and *she need but* need no *to* following them, not even in American English.  You are making up a distinction that does not exist.

Comment: And ["I need hardly remind you"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+need+hardly+remind+you%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) that lots of Americans speak real *English*. Okay - I admit that does sound a bit "haughty", even to a Brit!