# Why can no-one say "no-one needs know"?

Tags: meaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why use “need not” instead of “do not need to”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29409/why-use-need-not-instead-of-do-not-need-to)

In English, why could I say, "No-one need know" and not "No-one needs know".  I would say, after all, "No-one needs to know".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why use "need not" instead of "do not need to"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29409/why-use-need-not-instead-of-do-not-need-to) ; Also see [“need just” vs. “need to just”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29570/need-just-vs-need-to-just)

Comment: One dare not guess why modal verbs never inflect in English, nor need one look far afield before finding examples aplenty. It oughtn’t seem strange when considered in that particular light.

Comment: Right. Modals are just plain **weird**. And so are Negatives.